# Using Microsoft Graph API to upload file to onedrive in MVC Application, Error with permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to upload files to the onedrive of a user. I am trying to use the c# SDK to upload the files. But I get an Error saying :

Code: accessDenied

Message: The caller does not have permission to perform the action.

Can someone help me resolve these permission issues?

I have set up my application in Azure, I have added the user to the app. I have Added Microsoft Graph API Permissions:
Delegated permissions : User.Read Files.Read Files.Read.All Files.ReadWrite.All Sites.Read.All Sites.ReadWrite.All offline_access openid profile

This is the Code i Use to Sign in with the Graph SDK:

```
  GraphServiceClient client = new GraphServiceClient(new  GraphAuthenticationProvider());
```

This is the AuthenticationProvider

```
  public class GraphAuthenticationProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
{
    AzureTokenResponse tokenRes;

    public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        try
        {
            if (tokenRes == null || tokenRes.ExpirationDate < DateTime.Now)
            {
                string tokenEndpointUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + "{domain}" + "/oauth2/token";

                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
             new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "{username}"),
             new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "{password}"),
             new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "{clientid}"),
             new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "{clientsecret}"),
             new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
             new KeyValuePair<string,string>("scope","User.Read Files.Read Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Sites.Read.All Sites.ReadWrite.All"),
             new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", "https://graph.microsoft.com")
            });

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage res = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndpointUri, content);

                    string json = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    tokenRes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AzureTokenResponse>(json);

                    tokenRes.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Parse("1970/01/01");

                    int seconds = 0;

                    int.TryParse(tokenRes.Expires_on, out seconds);

                    tokenRes.ExpirationDate = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(tokenRes.ExpirationDate.AddSeconds(seconds));
                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenRes.AccessToken);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    class AzureTokenResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("access_token")]
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
        public string Expires_in { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("expires_on")]
        public string Expires_on { get; set; }

        public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    }

}
```

This is the calls i am trying to make: Upload File:

```
   string path = Path.GetTempFileName();

        file.SaveAs(path);

        byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

        Stream filestream = new MemoryStream(data);

        DriveItem doc = await client.Me.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(file.FileName).Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(filestream);
```

Get Link to file:

```
   Microsoft.Graph.Permission permission = await client.Me.Drive.Items[doc.Id].CreateLink("embed", "anonymous").Request().PostAsync();
```

I get the access token, but when I try to use it to upload files, I get the Error saying I lack permissions

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the MSAL library for Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with more or less the same topic. As far as I can figure out Graph only supports File Actions (read/write) on OneDrive for Business (Delegated) or SharePoint (Delegated and Application Permissions).